# Reactjs - How to Bring Users Back To Their Previous Spot of list item on back click

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll

Can anyone help me with following issue:
Currently I am infinitely loading item list by giving page numbers in API call. Say I am calling item list api with page = 1 then page 2 (once it reaches end of 1st page items it loads next page) and so on.

Say currently I am on page 3. If user clicks any of the item on page 3, he will be redirected to details page. And if he clicks browsers back button, he should be back to clicked item of page 3 not at the top of page i.e first item of list.

How can I achieve this?

FYI `componentDidMount` calls api's first time and the later on `onScroll` method calls with next pages

**Solution I tried**:
 keep clicked item position and page in redux. And once I am back to list I will load api's till saved 'page number' doesn't loads. And once expected page loads I will scroll to item position. 
==> Problem with this solution is user will have to wait for response of expected page number and once expected page number's result comes it will scroll to clicked item position. So that seems annoying!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Root>{routes(pages)}</Root>
      </Router>
```

Add this in Your App.Js, Use browserHistory. Later In your component you can use something like

this.props.history.goBack();

Bind the action with button/anchor tag.

Thanks

Comment: When you are sending the user to the detail page, Along with that also send the scroll position by using the Ref & handle the same by pushing it to history.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `localStorage` to save the response that you got from the server and when the user comes back to your page you can show him the response immediately and also update the list in the background.

Service worker is a good way for doing this too .

Comment: So you mean I need to store all pages data into redux/localstorage. And when user come back to list show saved list and scroll to particular item immediately?

Btw what to update in background?

Comment: Yes i mean you can store the latest data in the `localStorage` and set the store immediately after the user came in, then send an http request and get the data again and update the `localStorage` to the latest data

Comment: @VikasHiran and you can do this by doing something like this code in the reducer : ```data: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data')) || [],```

Comment: but what if data is large? Is it wise to store in localstorage/redux?

Comment: @VikasHiran Is detail page located in the Rouer ? How do you redirect user to another page ?